# MYSQL - ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have successfully been adding foreign key constraints to tables, but suddenly mysql has started throwing this error at me. I have read previous posts for the most probably causes of this error and none of them seem to apply to my case. Here are my create statements

```
CREATE TABLE activity (
    id SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR (200) NULL,
    ageGroup VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    createdBy TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UNIQUE KEY (name)
);


mysql>
CREATE TABLE activity_game (
    id SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR (200) NULL,
    activityId SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    createdBy TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (activityId) REFERENCES actvity (id)
);
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
mysql>
```

Version: '5.6.13'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a misspell on

REFERENCES **actvity**